# How to get full width in body element

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, resize

How would I be able to get a website to auto-fit in the page?

It's a landscape design which needs no scrolling.

Answer (score 24):

You should set `body` and `html` to [`position:fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), and then set [`right:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right), [`left:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left), [`top:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top), and [`bottom:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom) to `0;`. That way, even if content overflows it will not extend past the limits of the viewport.

For example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3A2jn/2/)

**Caveat**: Using this method, if the user makes their window smaller, content will be cut off.

Comment: i having the same issue while making window smaller i don't want the content to cut off, instead fit with respect to window height. How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 13):

If its in a landscape then you will be needing more width and less height! That's just what all websites have.

Lets go with a basic first then the rest!

**The basic CSS:**

By CSS you can do this,

```
#body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Here you are using a div with `id` body, as:

```
<body>
  <div id="body>
    all the text would go here!
  </div>
</body>
```

Then you can have a web page with `100%` height and width.

**What if he tries to resize the window?**

The issues pops up, what if he tries to resize the window? Then all the elements inside `#body` would try to mess up the UI. For that you can write this:

```
#body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

And just add `min-height` `max-height` `min-width` and `max-width`.

This way, the page element would stay at the place they were at the page load.

**Using JavaScript:**

Using JavaScript, you can control the UI, use jQuery as:

```
$('#body').css('min-height', '100%');
```

And all other remaining CSS properties, and JS will take care of the User Interface when the user is trying to resize the window.

**How to not add scroll to the web page:**

If you are not trying to add a scroll, then you can use this JS

```
$('#body').css('min-height', screen.height); // or anyother like window.height
```

This way, the document will get a new height whenever the user would load the page.

Second option is better, because when users would have different screen resolutions they would want a CSS or Style sheet created for their own screen. Not for others!

**Tip:** So try using JS to find current Screen size and edit the page! :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use CSS to do it for example

```
<style>
html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#DDD;
}
</style>
```

Comment: the background color is just to show you