# Need text to be 100% height and width of window, no more, no less

Tags: html, css, user-interface, viewport, font-size

I have a page with absolutely no interface at all. It is literally just a string of text (it grabs text every X seconds that could be of various lengths in terms of characters and words.) I need this text to fill exactly 100% of the browser window height and width. Basically the window would be just this string (using whatever Google Font I need) and nothing else (I suppose it could have a bit of a margin but not much)

The text cannot spill over length-wise or height-wise to where scrolling is needed, as there is not user interface to scroll (this is being displayed on a monitor with no keyboard or mouse)... sort of like a sign, but digital.

I have tried everything I know, I am not a UI person, I know very generally how to make a page responsive. I also can use a lot of JQuery if needed. No Angular, etc.

(This will be on a desktop browser, but I assume it would work on mobile too. Again, 100% height and width and no more or no less)

Comment: so when the text is too long you want the font size to automatically shrink so as to fit the page?

Comment: Did you try the approaches here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201715/how-do-i-get-a-page-to-auto-fit-to-a-window

Comment: @raghav710 - Yes, if the text is long or short, I don't care if it has line breaks or anything, I just want it to fill the page 100 high and 100% wide.  Or close to it (considering letters have different sizes).

Comment: Basically think of it like a traffic sign, you want to fill as much of the sign as possible with your text... and the text character count can vary

Comment: I also have this, but can remove it: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: see if this blog article help you https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/fluid-typography/

Comment: Tell me one, u need to set both attributes and what if your screen is not proportional? If u have e.g. 200 width and 1000 height, u want to force it ?

Comment: @downstairs I came across this plugin while searching for an answer: https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill. Can you check if this satisfies your requirement?

Comment: @FreeStyle09 - I want to force the text to use up as much of the whole window as possible, regardless of browser window size.  That is all.

Comment: @raghav710: the jquery-text fill is causing an error.  Should I be using a certain version of jquery?

Comment: @downstairs in this [sample](http://jquery-textfill.github.io/example/) I see that the Jquery version used is jQuery v1.11.0. What is the one you have?

Comment: Can u use bootstrap for this? Or u need pure css html

Answer (score 0):

you can set height and width as 'auto' because it will take automatically screen height and width. So, your text should spread according to the screen width and height.

Comment: Do you have the CSS for this?  Again, not an expert.  What attributes would be "auto" and what is the syntax?

Comment: No i haven't css for this but i suggest you to use height and width as auto like in asp.net. Because it should fetch automatically screen's height and width.

Comment: Like this?  This does not work... `<div class="sayinghtml" id="sayinghtml" style="height:auto;width:auto;font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;" align="center">This is a bunch of random text of any length</div>`

Comment: but it works for me when i use this. I think your css content can change this runtime. so please check

Comment: my content can change at runtime?  It actually may change as I load new text.  But either way, check out: https://jsfiddle.net/downstairs/o3wzbc30/

Answer (score 0):

You can use vh unit like this

```
.textclass { 
   font-size: 100vh;
   white-space: nowrap; /* add this line if you want to text in single line */
}
```

you also need to remove padding margin of body and html

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: This makes the text HUGE and well beyond the height and width of the window.

Comment: if possible please give fiddle URL so, I can help you.

Comment: I don't know what a fiddle URL is?  But really, all we're talking about here is the most basic HTML page with one DIV with text in that DIV that can be any random string of words.  That's all it is.  html, head with CSS, body, this div.  Nothing else.  And since nothing I am doing is working, it really isn't relevant all the things I've tried in the div style and the CSS in the head.

Comment: @downstairs https://jsfiddle.net/ is a site where you can write HTML, CSS and JS and share it with others. If you could provide a minimal reproduction of your code in JSFiddle and share it as part of your question it would be easier for people to tweak and give you an answer that you can try out!

Comment: @raghav710 - Let me change the URL I just posted, here is my work: https://jsfiddle.net/downstairs/o3wzbc30/1/