# Windows browsers, Edge, Explorer 6 Chrome: Prevent page being at zoom: 0.5

Tags: html, css, windows, cross-browser, responsive

So I encountered a weird bug with a webproject in Chrome, Explorer and Edge, but only on Windows, and only on res. below `1440px` (I think). Just to be clear, I'm a mac-user and I'm using browserling to cross-browser check my site.

The problem is that the whole page looks zoomed out (text is small, margins around content large) and since I have a lot of `vh` and `vw` values in my CSS this obviously messes up the whole layout.

I tried a `zoom:0.5` in Chrome on a mac, and I got the same effect, so this seems to be the problem.

I tried to add a `zoom: 2` to the html for any windows, and tho the height looked correct the rest didn't fit.

In Chrome Mac and Windows Chrome > 1440px
[image]

In windows Edge, Explorer and Chrome:
[image]

With the `zoom: 2` on HTML (Section height of `100vh` is correct, but not size of and position of content
[image]

These are my meta-tags, nothing going on there right?:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> //tried to disable this, did nothing.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

This fixes most things on the site, but it DOES feel wrong with all the `200`-values:

```
section.has-bg-img,
    .page-section.has-bg-img,
    .content-section.has-bg-img {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 200vh !important;
    }

    section.has-bg-img .background-video {
        height: 200vh !important;
        min-height: -moz-available !important;          
        height: 100% !important;

        video {
            height: auto !important;
            width: auto !important;
            min-height: 200vh !important;
            min-width: 200% !important;

        }
    }

    .section.child-page-section .child-page-section-wrap {
         min-height: calc(200vh - 5em) !important;
    }

    body.home #page-section-top-section .section-wrap {
        max-width: none !important;
    }

    body.home header:not(.sticky-header)#page-header hgroup#site-titling #site-logo h1#site-logo-title {
        font-size: 5em !important;
    }

    section.scroll-to-next-slide .slide-to-section {
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-top: -0.15em;

        .slide-to-section-button {
            font-size: 10em;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a page to auto fit to a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201715/how-do-i-get-a-page-to-auto-fit-to-a-window)

Comment: Sorry, now seems like something else is going on, too bad seemed like an easy fix! :/ If that was the case the `100vh` would still work correctly right?